# Camel route to soap service

Tags: soap, apache-camel, endpoint

I'm new to camel.

I want to add following proxy route to soap service as run time.

```
from("cxf://http://localhost:8081/CentrelServer/NewWebService?" +                        
                    "serviceClass=com.vnitt.webservice.axis.NewWebService" +
                    "&serviceName={http://axis.webservice.vnitt.com/}NewWebService" +
                    "&portName={http://axis.webservice.vnitt.com/}NewWebServicePort" +
                    "&wsdlURL=src/conf/NewWebService.wsdl").
                            process(new Processor() {

                public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("code run here");

                }
            }).to(clientService);
```

In the above code i want clientService point to a soap service at address: `http://localhost:9091/Client/NewWebService`

I don't know how to create EndPoint clientService.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are some decent examples in the [official docs](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html).

This example (taken from the docs above) for instance (given you can configure this in spring).

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceEndpoint" address="http://localhost:9000/SoapContext/SoapPort"
        wsdlURL="testutils/hello_world.wsdl"
        serviceClass="org.apache.hello_world_soap_http.Greeter"
        endpointName="s:SoapPort"
        serviceName="s:SOAPService"
        xmlns:s="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http" />
```

or stright in the DSL route:

```
to("cxf://http://localhost:9000/SoapContext/SoapPort?" +                        
                "serviceClass=org.apache.hello_world_soap_http.Greeter" +
                "&serviceName={http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/}SOAPService" +
                "&endpointName={http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/}SoapPort" +
                "&wsdlURL=testutils/hello_world.wsdl")
```

It should be rather straight forward to substitue your target web service settings in this config. You need to generate Java classes etc for this code though.